# addEventListener click not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am creating a stop watch like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="stopwatch.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="but">
        <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
            <p id="timer">0</p>
            <button id="start">Start/Stop</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            <button id="record">Record Time</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the javascript:

```
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var sec = 0;
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", counter());

function counter(){
    setInterval(time(), 10);
}

function time(){
    sec++;
    timer.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

However, when I click the start button, it didn't work. Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the line:

```
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", counter());
```

it is wrong, it should be:

```
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", counter);
```

When you use the `()`, it is calling the function. Here, you are passing the function to `addEventListener`, not calling it.

Same as on the line:

```
setInterval(time(), 10);
```

it should be:

```
setInterval(time, 10);
```

---

So your code should be:

```js
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var sec = 0;
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", counter);

function counter(){
    setInterval(time, 10);
}

function time(){
    sec++;
    timer.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="stopwatch.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="but">
        <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
            <p id="timer">0</p>
            <button id="start">Start/Stop</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            <button id="record">Record Time</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are have to *pass* the function and *not* call them *immediately*:

1. Change `document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", counter());` to `document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", counter);`
2. Change `setInterval(time(), 10);` to `setInterval(time, 10);`

See demo below:

```js
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var sec = 0;
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", counter);

function counter(){
    setInterval(time, 10);
}

function time(){
    sec++;
    timer.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="stopwatch.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="but">
        <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
            <p id="timer">0</p>
            <button id="start">Start/Stop</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            <button id="record">Record Time</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```